# my android App is crashing when try to share it on what's app (which is not installed)

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, whatsapp

```
 Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newbutton);

        assert clickButton != null;

        clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {


    Intent uriIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("whatsapp://send?text=" + "Text you want to share"));

  startActivity(uriIntent);

 }

   });
```

Comment: Add the crash log to your question.

Comment: U seem to have added new. Why a . Over there?

Comment: Thanks, As I am a newbie. What if the user hasn't installed the what's app, A message should be prompted with "what's app not installed other than crashing. much appreciated.

Comment: @arvindersingh Check the solution given below

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behaviour since it is absolutely plausible that some users don't have certain apps installed. You need to check if there are any activities which can handle the intent by calling `intent.resolveActivity()` and checking if the result is not null.

The development documentation on intents and intent filters states it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#ExampleSend):

> Caution: It's possible that a user won't have any apps that handle the
>   implicit intent you send to `startActivity()`. Or, an app may be
>   inaccessible because of profile restrictions or settings put into
>   place by an administrator. If that happens, the call fails and your
>   app crashes. To verify that an activity will receive the intent, call
>   `resolveActivity()` on your Intent object. If the result is non-null,
>   there is at least one app that can handle the intent and it's safe to
>   call `startActivity()`. If the result is null, do not use the intent
>   and, if possible, you should disable the feature that issues the
>   intent. The following example shows how to verify that the intent
>   resolves to an activity. This example doesn't use a URI, but the
>   intent's data type is declared to specify the content carried by the
>   extras.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your intent is not found any activity which you wants to open.
so you need to handle `ActivityNotFoundException` like below

```
Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newbutton);

            assert clickButton != null;

            clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override

                public void onClick(View v) {

    try{
          Intent uriIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("whatsapp://send?text=" + "Text you want to share"));

      startActivity(uriIntent);
        }catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
          System.out.println("ERROR");
          System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
          failureCallback.invoke(ex.getMessage());
        }


     }

       });
```

Comment: after applying your code,getting this error, "MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)"

Comment: @Mehul Kabaria The Uri holding the whatsapp link itself states the intent to redirect to the Whatsapp app or browser.

Comment: Is there any alternative for this line "failureCallback.invoke(ex.getMessage());", as it is giving a lot of errors. to resolve "invoke" it tells "add target api annotation" and gives a lot of error while running it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the package name if the application is installed or not. If installed share it on whatsapp or call the native list of application which support share functionality.

Check conditions like this.

```
if(!appInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp")){
    // Toast message not installed.
}else{
    // Toast message installed.
}
```

Generic method to check any application installed or not

```
private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean isInstalled;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            isInstalled = true;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            isInstalled = false;
        }
        return isInstalled;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not targeting the correct Whatsapp uri:

**Use the below one.**

```
 Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Hello World!");
```